# Expansion Panels should expand onClicking the button | React Material

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a component with expansion panels. Now, it will expand the detail content, when user clicks on the expansion summary panel. What I want to achieve is, I am having a button called 'next' in each expanded details content. So, whenever the user clicks on the next button. It should closes the current expanded panel and should expand the next one.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles, ExpansionPanel, ExpansionPanelDetails, ExpansionPanelSummary, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Event';
import styles from '../../../../assets/css/style.js';

class Content extends React.Component {
  state = {
    expanded: null,
  };

  handleChange = panel => (event, expanded) => {
    this.setState({
      expanded: expanded ? panel : false,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { expanded } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className={classes.contentRoot}>
        <ExpansionPanel expanded={expanded === 'panel1'} onChange={this.handleChange('panel1')} className={classes.expansionRoot}>
          <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />} classes= {{ root: classes.expand, expandIcon: classes.expandMore}}>
            <Typography className={classes.heading} >One </Typography>
          </ExpansionPanelSummary>
          <ExpansionPanelDetails className={classes.expansionDetails}>
            Content
              <Button variant="outlined">Next</Button>
          </ExpansionPanelDetails>
        </ExpansionPanel>
        <ExpansionPanel expanded={expanded === 'panel2'} onChange={this.handleChange('panel2')} className={classes.expansionRoot}>
          <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />} classes= {{ root: classes.expand, expandIcon: classes.expandMore}}>
            <Typography className={classes.heading}>Two</Typography>
          </ExpansionPanelSummary>
          <ExpansionPanelDetails className={classes.expansionDetails}>
            Content
              <Button variant="outlined">Next</Button>
          </ExpansionPanelDetails>
        </ExpansionPanel>
        <ExpansionPanel expanded={expanded === 'panel3'} onChange={this.handleChange('panel3')} className={classes.expansionRoot}>
          <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />} classes= {{ root: classes.expand, expandIcon: classes.expandMore}}>
            <Typography className={classes.heading}>Three</Typography>
          </ExpansionPanelSummary>
          <ExpansionPanelDetails className={classes.expansionDetails}>
              Content
              <Button variant="outlined">Next</Button>
          </ExpansionPanelDetails>
        </ExpansionPanel>
        <ExpansionPanel expanded={expanded === 'panel4'} onChange={this.handleChange('panel4')} className={classes.expansionRoot}>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />} classes= {{ root: classes.expand, expandIcon: classes.expandMore}}>
            <Typography className={classes.heading}>Four</Typography>
          </ExpansionPanelSummary>
          <ExpansionPanelDetails className={classes.expansionDetails}>
           Content
              <Button variant="outlined">Next</Button>
          </ExpansionPanelDetails>
        </ExpansionPanel>
        <ExpansionPanel expanded={expanded === 'panel5'} onChange={this.handleChange('panel5')} className={classes.expansionRoot}>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />} classes= {{ root: classes.expand, expandIcon: classes.expandMore}}>
            <Typography className={classes.heading}>Five</Typography>
          </ExpansionPanelSummary>
          <ExpansionPanelDetails className={classes.expansionDetails}>
              Content
              <Button variant="outlined">Next</Button>
          </ExpansionPanelDetails>
        </ExpansionPanel>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Content.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Content);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not recursive at all but maybe you have your reasons. Well, as you are using strings to check your panel expanded state, you can use an method that take as parameter the string of next panel, something like this :

```
handleButtonClick = nextPanelString => (event, expanded) => {
    this.setState({
      expanded:  nextPanelString,
    });
  };
```

Then in render method :

```
<ExpansionPanel expanded={expanded === 'panel1'} onChange={this.handleChange('panel1')} className={classes.expansionRoot}>
          <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />} classes= {{ root: classes.expand, expandIcon: classes.expandMore}}>
            <Typography className={classes.heading} >One </Typography>
          </ExpansionPanelSummary>
          <ExpansionPanelDetails className={classes.expansionDetails}>
            Content
              <Button onClick={this.handleButtonClick('panel2')} variant="outlined">Next</Button>
          </ExpansionPanelDetails>
        </ExpansionPanel>
```

here is a Stackblitz working example :
[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/xaszdr?file=demo.js)

Again, you example is not recursive, I would recommend using a loop for that but if this is enough for your need so be it :)

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Yeah, I am working with loops. It is just for an UI demo. So, I made it to simply.